# Adjoint map is a Derivation (Lie-algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, lie-derivative

Let $L$ be a Lie-Algebra over $k$, $gl(k)$ as usual. Let $ad_x:L \rightarrow L$, given by $y \mapsto [x,y]$. Show that $ad_x$ is Derivation, i.e. $ad_x([y,z])=[ad_x(y),z]+[y,ad_x(z)]$.

I think the way to go here is using the Jacobi identity:

$$[x,[y,z]]+[z,[x,y]+[y,[z,x]]=0 \leftrightarrow ad_x([y,z])=-[z,[x,y]-[y,[z,x]]$$

Now using the Antisymmetric, we get $-[z,[x,y]]=[[x,y],z]=[ad_x(y),z]$ (what to do if $char(k)=2$?). So I have to show that $-[y,[z,x]]=[y,ad_x(z)]$. However, I get $-[y,[z,x]]=[-[x,z],y]$ and I do not know how to go on.

Comment: Yes, the Jacobi identity (when arranged properly) is _exactly_ the assertion that the adjoint map is a Lie algebra map $\mathfrak g \to {\mathrm {End}}\,\mathfrak g$.

Comment: You are on the right track, $-[y,[z,x]]=[y,-[z,x]]=[y,[x,z]]$ which is what you require

Comment: @123 aaah is $-[y,[z,x]]=[y,-[z,x]]$ justified by the linearity of the lie-bracket?. So does $-[x,y]=[-x,y]=[x,-y]$ hold in general? Thanks for your answer

Comment: The lie-bracket has the property that is is bilinear (that is linear in both of its arguments).